# How to pinch and zoom or pan the ARCore camera. Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

How to pinch and zoom or pan the ARCore camera.

Most importantly is it possible or i just been an idiot and there is no solution to do so.

Example:  using the ARCore Device from the GoogleARCore->Examples-> HelloAR

Seems to me the fieldview is locked and can not be modified

I tried with the normal camera and it works fine to pinch and zoom, but something about the AR camera does not like.

here is the code i tried
basic pinch to zoom mechanic using the multitouch inputs of a mobile device
[pinch and zoom](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/pinch-zoom)

Comment: Since an AR Camera shows the real world, i think it doesn't make much sense to zoom or pan it. The AR Camera has to be aligned with the phone's camera to behave well, so it's movement should be controlled only by the user. What you can do is change the scale of the AR objects, giving a feeling of zoom.

Comment: I thought of that. my goal was to create a measure app but to get more precision need to able to zoom in.  and if i zoom the object just makes it worst for precision